# Backbone.js paging, remove page number from Backbone.history.fragment

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I want to create page navigation for my app written in Backbone.

when I want to create the page navigation, I'm having problem with creating the URL.

```
<a href="' + Backbone.history.fragment + '/some_page_number">some_page_number</a>
```

because  Backbone.history.fragment will return path/to/1

the code above will return path/to/1/some_page_number.

while I want it to be

path/to/some_page_number.

how can I make it so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
<a href="' + MyApp.Utils.linkToPage( some_page_number ) + '">some_page_number</a>

// code no tested
MyApp.Utils.linkToPage = function( page ) {
  return Backbone.history.fragment.replace( /\/\d*$/, "" ) + "/" + page;
}
```

Maybe the RegExp is not properly defined but you can make an idea.